# Handlebars: href being rendered in template with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, puppeteer, express-handlebars

I have some code in a handlebars template that has a link with an href attribute.

```
    <body class="body">
      <div class="container w-container">
        <section class="wf-section">
            <div class="column-2 w-col w-col-3">
              <a class="link-2" href="www.google.com">help@website.org.za</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </body>
```

However when the handlebars are then compiled into HTML using handlebars and rendered into a PDF using Puppeteer the href is actually rendered as text which is obviously not what I want as seen in the screenshot.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Puppeteer code

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    executablePath: execPath,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent(html); //html from handlebars

const pdf = await page.pdf({printBackground:true});
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Can you show a [mcve] with the handlebars code that reads and compiles this template?